# How to removing entries satisfying given criteria from an array (MatLab)

Tags: matlab

I have a `cell A` whose entries are polynomials such as

```
A{1} = DocPolynom([1 2 3]).
```

I would like to remove those entries `i of A` for which `length(double(A{i})) ~=2.`

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: A{1} is not a reference to an array but to a cell array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
inds2remove=cellfun(@(x) length(double(x))~=2,A);
A( inds2remove )=[];
```

Comment: Replace the last x on line 1 with A.

Comment: upperBound's suggestion worked. Thanks, both of you. cellfun seems useful - I feel I should read up on it.

Comment: CELLFUN and its friend ARRAYFUN are definitely worth getting to know. (And, of course, you can use ARRAYFUN on cell arrays if you wish)